# how do you convert a string into a Json object to return to a jquery getJson call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

i have code in csharp that returns this string:

**{'dateTimeFormat': 'iso8601',
'wikiURL': "http://simile.mit.edu/shelf/",
'wikiSection': "Simile Cubism Timeline",
'events' : [
{'start': '1924',
'title': 'Barfusserkirche',
'description': 'by Lyonel Feininger, American/German Painter, 1871-1956',
'image': 'http://images.allposters.com/images/AWI/NR096_b.jpg',
'link': 'http://www.allposters.com/-sp/Barfusserkirche-1924-Posters_i1116895_.htm'
}
]
}**

i want to ship this back to my view as a JSon structure, but it doesn't seem to be working:

here is my controller code:

```
   public JsonResult GetTimeLineJson(int id)
    {
        RoadmapItem item = new RoadmapItem();
        string timelineString = [There is a function here that returns the string above];

        return Json(timelineString);
    }
```

and here is my jquery code:

```
      var URL = "/Business/GetTimeLineJson/" + resourceId;

      $.getJSON(URL, function(data) {
             $('#deskView').show();
             onLoad(data);
       });
```

any idea whats going wrong here

Comment: Did you verify that, at the time you call $.getJSON(), you're actually getting that string back from the server?

Comment: Check if data is json object. If so, then its probably onLoad which is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example the **string** `{'dateTimeFormat': ...-1924-Posters_i1116895_.htm' } ] }` would be JSON-encoded and sent to the client, i.e. the data is double-encoded.

Would it be possible to skip the `string timelineString =...` line and pass the "raw" data to the Json() method?
Exactly what is `[There is a function here that returns the string above]` doing?

edit:
Whatever you pass to Controller.Json(object) gets json/javascript-encoded (by Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer) before being sent to the client.
E.g. if you want to send an array with "a" and "b" as elements (json-encoded)  the client must receive the string `["a","b"]`. But if you pass `["a","b"]` to Controller.Json() the client will receive `"[\"a\",\"b\"]"`

You probably want

```
return Content(timelineString, "application/json");
```

see [Controller..::.Content Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.content.aspx)

Comment: To answer your question, the function is simply building up the string.   I thought i was passing in the raw string to teh Json method ??

Comment: @VolkerK - this was a response to your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can user this:

```
RoadmapItem item = new RoadmapItem();

return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
```

JsonConvert is a member of Newtonsoft.Json.dll. You can reed about it and download it here: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx

Of course method GetTimeLineJson can return string ;)